# Include other columns when doing groupBy and agg in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I ave a Dataset that looks like this:

```
+--------------------+---------+------+--------------------+
|             transID|principal|subSeq|          subTransID|
+--------------------+---------+------+--------------------+
|2116e07b-14ea-476...|      bob|     4|ec463751-22ca-477...|
|3859a175-f16b-4fd...|      bob|     4|ec463751-22ca-477...|
|3859a175-f16b-4fd...|      bob|     7|2116e07b-14ea-476...|
+--------------------+---------+------+--------------------+
```

I want to remove duplicate rows by aggregating the column `transID` based on the maximum value of the column `subSeq`, but I want to resultant Dataset to show not the `max(subSeq)` column, but instead the column `subTransID` from the original Dataset.

If I do this:

```
dsJoin.groupBy("transID").agg(functions.max("subSeq")).show();
```

Then I get

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|             transID|max(subSeq)|
+--------------------+-----------+
|3859a175-f16b-4fd...|          7|
|2116e07b-14ea-476...|          4|
+--------------------+-----------+
```

The duplicate row `3859a175-f16b-4fd...` with value 4 in column `subSeq` has been correctly removed based on the max value 7 in another row. But I want to have the column `subTransID` shown in the resultant Dataset!

I must be missing something very obvious here.

Doing this in JAVA. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `agg` expression also get `first` from the others fields

```
dsJoin.groupBy("transID").agg(functions.max("subSeq"),functions.first("principal")).show();
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it -- except it looks like what I need here is not .first() but .last()? Anyway, this way it seems to do what I need it to do.

Comment: If "other" values are the same it doesn't matter which copy you take

Comment: this only works if all `subTransID` per `transID` are the same, I'm not sure if thats the case here

Answer (score 3):

You should pack the relevant attributes into a struct, apply the aggregate-function and then unpack the struct again ((scala-code below) :

```
dsJoin.groupBy("transID")
.agg(
     max(struct("subSeq","subTransID")).as("max")
)
.select("transID","max.*")
.show()
```

Comment: So Spark is finding the `max` only on the first element of the `struct` while the other elements in the `struct` play no role for the max?

Comment: @BjörnJacobs If the first element ist equal, then the second element of the struct will also play a role